# How to save data using mongodb query in middleware in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to save data using mongodb query using middleware in node.js. please provide some code with example?

Comment: what framework are you using ?

Comment: Nodejs  framework

Comment: Nodejs  is actually not a framework or a library, but a runtime environment, based on Chrome's V8 JavaScript engine.

Comment: a Node.js framework examples: Hapi.js, Express.js, Koa.js ...

Comment: I mean to say code wise middleware not by framework example

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It works both for insert and update (upsert).

```
// app.js

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const mongodb_url = process.env.MONGO_URL || "mongodb://localhost:27017";
const mongodb_dbname = 'test_db';
const port = process.env.PORT || 3006;

const app = express();
app.use(express.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ extended: true}));

app.post('/api/post/:identifier', (req, res) => {
    const identifier = req.params.identifier;
    const content = req.body.payload;
    MongoClient.connect(`${mongodb_url}`, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, client) => {
        if (!err) {
            let db = client.db(mongodb_dbname);
            db.collection('posts')
                .updateOne(
                    { identifier: identifier },
                    { $set: { content: content } },
                    { upsert: true }
                )
                .then((output) => {
                    res.status(202).send({ message: "Sent"});
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    res.status(500).send({
                        error_code: 500,
                        error_message: `Error while updating data - ${error}`
                    });
                });
            client.close();
        } else {
            res.status(500).send({
                error_code: 500,
                error_message: 'Error while connecting to database'
            });
        }
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`API bootstrapped on port ${port}...`);
});
```

Use the following `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "mongo-upsert",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.0"
  }
}
```

When invoked as `localhost:3006/api/post/my-post` with a request body containing:

```
{
    "payload": "Hello world"
}
```

This code is going to upsert a MongoDB document like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f3d272cbd52c9c109ea9baa"),
    "identifier" : "my-post",
    "content" : "Hello world"
}
```

Prerequisites  for the above code to work:

1. To have a working installation of `mongodb`
2. To have a database named `test_db`
3. To have a collection named `posts`

In this example, we are adding a post `content`, identified by an `identifier`, which for the sake of simplicity I have added as a path param in the `POST` definition.

Install dependencies using `npm install`.
Run the app using `npm start`.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [W3Schools NodeJS MongoDB](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb.asp).

I don't have enough rep to comment so here's an answer.